# The solvability of a Hölder ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is as follows, I want to know whether there is a function $u\in \text{C}^{0}\left((-1,1)\right)$ but not $\text{C}^1((-1,1))$, such that $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{|u(x+h)-u(x)|}{\left|h\right|^{1/2}}=\sqrt{|x|},\forall x\in(-1,1)$.

I get this problem while constructing a counterexample for the problem:

If $\alpha+\beta=1,u\in\text{C}^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),$and $v=\dfrac{u(x+he)-u(x)}{|h|^\alpha}\in\text{C}^{0,\beta}(\Omega)$,where $e$  is a unit vector and $h$ is a small real number, then $u \in\text{C}^1(\Omega)$.

What I need is the existence of such a function $u$.

Comment: I'm sure there is no such $u$. Rather than try to come up with a proof of its non-existence (which won't help you solve the problem), I'd like to understand the problem itself. You say $v\in C^{0,\beta}(\Omega)$ -- is this true for all small $h$ and all unit vectors $e$? Is there a uniform bound on $C^{0,\beta}$ norm of $v$. (A bound independent of $e,h$?)

Comment: Yes, there is a uniform bound on $C^{0,\beta}$ norm of $v$ independent of $e$,$h$, and $h$ is small enough such that $v$ can be defined. You can get this problem on Page 46 of the book"Fully nonlinear elliptic equation " by Luis A.Caffarelli and Xavier Cabre, the American mathematical socity colloquium publications vol 43. Finally, my question is weather I can get a uniform  $C^1$ bound of $u$ while $\alpha+\beta =1$.